# can`t configure/register dockerized gitlab runner

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have running container with `gitlab`.

Also I try setup dockerized `gitlab runner` by [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html) article.

First i tried run gitlab runner by:

```
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

logs says:

```
...
Listen address not defined, session server disabled  builds=0
ERROR: Failed to load config stat /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml: no such file or directory  builds=0
ERROR: Failed to load config stat /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml: no such file or directory  builds=0
...
```

Also I tried register runner by [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html#docker) article:

```
docker run --rm -t -i -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner register
```

after 5 step:

```
Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated):
 my-tag,another-tag
```

I get error:

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=KuwydETA status=couldn't execute POST against http://localhost/api/v4/runners: Post http://localhost/api/v4/runners: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: getsockopt: connection refused
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

Answer (score 3):

In the `/srv/gitlab-runner/config` directory you need to insert the `config.toml` file.

You can locate the registration token at:

```
https://{your_gitlab_host}/project_namespace/project_name/runners
```

Create a temporary configuration file using the following as a template:

```
$ cat > /tmp/test-config.template.toml << EOF
[[runners]]
[runners.docker]
[[runners.docker.services]]
name = "mysql:latest"
[[runners.docker.services]]
name = "redis:latest"
EOF
```

You can now register the runner using the configuration file you just created:

```
gitlab-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  --url "https://gitlab.com" \
  --registration-token "$REGISTRATION_TOKEN" \
  --template-config /tmp/test-config.template.toml \
  --description "gitlab-ce-ruby-2.7" \
  --executor "docker" \
  --docker-image ruby:2.7
```

Source: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/examples/gitlab.html

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html